# how to use php and jquery reverse a function

Tags: php, jquery

hello all I am trying to  to reverse the following function to get the serialized data my code is as

```
  var pre_data='<?php echo json_encode( unserialize( $img));?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

```
var reversed_data='<?php echo serialize( json_decode( $img));?>';
```

**Details:**

- [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is reverse function for [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)
- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is reverse function of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: thanks for the response but I have already tried that and the output of both are different.

Comment: it returns " N;"